# How to count SQL based on a DateTime and an other variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, count, window-functions

I have a SQL table with failed testresults:

```
Run           Test              DateTime
1             20                2020-01-01 00:01
1             20                2020-01-01 00:00
1             20                2020-01-01 00:04
2             21                2020-01-01 00:10
2             21                2020-01-01 00:03
```

This table is telling me that the test has failed, but I want to know if it is the first, second or third test. In the end I would like to do it with a logo where a x stands for a failed test, and a X for the concerned test, like this way:

```
Run           Test              StartTime              Status
1             20                2020-01-01 00:01       xXx
1             20                2020-01-01 00:00       Xxx
1             20                2020-01-01 00:04       xxX
2             21                2020-01-01 00:10       xX
2             21                2020-01-01 00:03       Xx
```

It has to do something with COUNT and SUM, but I couldn't find out where to start with this case. Can you help me?

Comment: For the record: the column names DateTime and StartTime are meant to be the same. Because different answers uses them both I won't change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a weird requirement, but I think this does what you want:

```
select stuff(replicate('x', count(*) over (partition by run, test)),
             row_number() over (partition by run, test order by starttime), 1, 'X'
            ) as status
from t;
```

This uses string operations to construct the status string.

Comment: @GMB . . . It is also simpler and was several minutes earlier.  Alas.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you want `row_number()` and a window `count()`:

```
select t.*, 
    row_number() over(partition by run, test order by datetime) rn,
    count(*) over(partition by run, test) cnt
from mytable t
```

From there on, you can generate the "status" with string functions:

```
select t.*, 
    replicate('x', rn - 1) + 'X' + replicate('x', cnt - rn) status
from (
    select t.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by run, test order by datetime) rn,
        count(*) over(partition by run, test) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f8ca308e55ab6cdda0fdbe186bfb2a69)**:

```
Run | Test | DateTime         | rn | cnt | status
--: | ---: | :--------------- | -: | --: | :-----
  1 |   20 | 2020-01-01 00:00 |  1 |   3 | Xxx   
  1 |   20 | 2020-01-01 00:01 |  2 |   3 | xXx   
  1 |   20 | 2020-01-01 00:04 |  3 |   3 | xxX   
  2 |   21 | 2020-01-01 00:03 |  1 |   2 | Xx    
  2 |   21 | 2020-01-01 00:10 |  2 |   2 | xX
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I'm looking for! For my understanding: the left and right function are only to define how many x's you want right? If you change left to right and vice versa it doesn't matter?

Comment: @Japie07: yes, you are right. This has me thinking that we don't need `left()` and `right()`, we can move the logic to `replicate()`. I updated my answer.