# How to set a new SQL variable based on a DateTime and an other variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, count, window-functions

My previous question is answered ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64054872/how-to-count-sql-based-on-a-datetime-and-an-other-variable)), but I would like to extend it. To avoid confusion I ask it in this question:

I have a SQL table with failed testresults:

```
Run           Test              StartTime              Result
1             20                2020-01-01 00:01       Failed
1             20                2020-01-01 00:00       NotExecuted
1             20                2020-01-01 00:04       Timeout
2             21                2020-01-01 00:10       Failed
2             21                2020-01-01 00:03       Failed
```

This table is telling me that the test has failed, but I want to know if it is the first, second or third test. I also want to know which test I'm looking at. To use capital letters seems a reasonable idea, as long as every value in Result as a different starting letter, and for now that is the case. However I'm open to other idea's.

```
Run           Test              StartTime              Result          ResultStatus
1             20                2020-01-01 00:01       Failed          nFt
1             20                2020-01-01 00:00       NotExecuted     Nft
1             20                2020-01-01 00:04       Timeout         nfT
2             21                2020-01-01 00:10       Failed          fF
2             21                2020-01-01 00:03       Failed          Ff
```

When using the replicate function as said in the answer on the other question, how can I scale to more result outcomes?

Comment: Please explain what `ResultStatus` means and how you want to calculate it.

Comment: Human eyes will struggle to see "F" vs. 'f'. This is a bad encoding idea.

Comment: @SMor In the program I'll use icons, which I determine based on the letter, so the user won't see the letters like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can construct this using `string_agg()`:

```
select t.*,
       string_agg(lower(left(result, 1)), '') within group (order by starttime) over (partition by run, test) as resultstatus
from t;
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server doesn't support `string_agg()` as a window function. so let's use a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select string_agg(lower(left(t2.result, 1)), '') within group (order by t2.starttime) 
        from t t2
        where t2.run = t.run and t2.test = t.test
       ) as resultstatus
from t;
```

Upper-casing the current test is tricky.  Here is one method:

```
select t.*,
       stuff(rs, seqnum, 1, left(result, 1)) as resultstatus
from (select t.*,
             (select string_agg(lower(left(t2.result, 1)), '') within group (order by t2.starttime) 
              from t t2
              where t2.run = t.run and t2.test = t.test
             ) as rs,
             row_number() over (partition by run, test order by starttime) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9a395225a6940ead1da8cdfbe398abaa) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Do you have tips how to get better with advanced queries like this? The docs from Microsoft are a bit vague I think.

Comment: @Japie07 . . . Practice.  Of course, I've also written a book on the subject which I recommend.